# The player moves due to the tilt of the mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't understand in any way that with the movement when the mouse is tilted down, I move backwards when I tilt up forward, as I realized this happens in the presence of gravity.

Most likely the problem is in FPSInput, since I tilted the player and deleted the MouseLook script, it didn't help

**What it looks like**: https://gifyu.com/image/AKcy

MouseLook:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{

    public enum RotationAxes
    {
        MouseXAndY = 0,
        MouseX = 1,
        MouseY = 2
    }

    public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;
    public float sensitivityHor = 9.0f;
    public float sensitivityVert = 9.0f;
    public float minimumVert = -45.0f;
    public float maximumVert = 45.0f;
    private float _rotationX = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        Rigidbody body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if (body != null)
            body.freezeRotation = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityHor, 0);
        }
        else if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseY)
        {
            _rotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityVert;
            _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX, minimumVert, maximumVert);
            float rotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y;
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(_rotationX, rotationY, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            _rotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityVert;
            _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX, minimumVert, maximumVert);
            float delta = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityHor;
            float rotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y + delta;

            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(_rotationX, rotationY, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

FPSInput:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
[AddComponentMenu("Control Script/FPS Input")]

public class FPSInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 6.0f;
    public float gravity = -9.8f;
    private CharacterController _charController;

    void Start()
    {
        _charController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float deltaX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
        float deltaZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(deltaX, 0, deltaZ);
        movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(movement, speed);
        movement.y = gravity;
        movement *= Time.deltaTime;
        movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement);
        _charController.Move(movement);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most probably do **NOT** want the gravity to be applied in local space. This way if you look up you move forward and if you look down you move backward.

Rather you want the User input be applied in local space but the Y axis to be taken in global space.

Rather do e.g.

```
var deltaX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
var deltaZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
var movement = new Vector3(deltaX, 0, deltaZ);
// Rather first clamp to 1, then multiply by the speed
movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(movement, 1) * speed;
// first convert local to global space
movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement);
// then overwrite the now global Y axis with the gravity 
// This at the same time also prevents User from flying upwards
// when looking up and walking forward
movement.y = gravity;
_charController.Move(movement * Time.deltaTime);
```